# AdvanceFilter throws a 1004 error, object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

> I get a runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error when my code gets to the advance filter line.

I tried to record a macro, which works, but when I adjust the range to be dynamic, I start getting the error. I also tried to type it out very carefully to follow the prompts.

```
Private Sub LogOffenders()
    Dim Month As Integer
    Dim SID1001 As Range
    Dim MonSID  As Range
    Dim SIDRowCount As Long
    Dim OffCol As Integer
    Dim LasMon As Range
    Dim UniOff As Long
    Dim UniCount As Long

    'Count row
    SIDRowCount = Worksheets("1001").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    OffCol = Int(Format(Date, "mm"))

    Set SID1001 = Worksheets("1001").Range("C2:C" & SIDRowCount)
    Set MonSID = Worksheets("OffLog").Range(Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(2, OffCol), Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(SIDRowCount, OffCol))

    If OffCol = 1 Then
        Set LasMon = Worksheets("OffLog").Range(Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(2, 12), Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(SIDRowCount, 12))
    Else:
        Set LasMon = Worksheets("OffLog").Range(Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(2, OffCol - 1), Worksheets("OffLog").Cells(SIDRowCount, OffCol))
    End If

    'copy SIDs to SID log.
        SID1001.Copy
        MonSID.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'Count number of unique SIDs in copied column
        LasMon.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("OffLog").Range("P"), unique:=True  '**Code breaks here***
        UniCount = Worksheets("1001").Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

I want to copy the unique values in the P column and then count the number of values.

> I get a runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: `Range("P")` is not valid. Try `Range("P1")` or `Range("P:P")`.

Comment: I'm silly. Thanks so much. I knew it was something simple.